# ProgramName.vshost.exe_Url_ and ProgramName.exe_Url_

Tags: vb.net

VS 2015. Years and years that when I run a program from IDE in Debug mode is created a Local Folder "ProgramName.vshost.exe_Url_random chars", if I run a program from IDE in Release mode is created another folder "ProgramName.vshost.exe_Url_random chars", while If I run directly the program from the .exe file is created a "ProgramName.exe_Url_" folder for each position of the .exe.

So doing each program has its user.config file.

Yesterday I have created a new program, that from anywhere I run it (IDE or .exe, Debug or Release) is created **only one single folder** with a single user.config file.

**WHY**? VS settings seems the same of always. Some setting to change?

Comment: Don't get too attached to this behavior, more of a bug than a feature.  The Visual Studio Hosting process (aka vshost) is retired in VS2017.  The hash is still affected by the EXE file location.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: I have deleted the "obj" folder.

At new startup from IDE now is regularly created a  "ProgramName.vshost.exe_Url_random chars" folder.